# Backcountry bridge

Tags: construction

I  am tasked with constructing a bridge.. Lifelong carpenter, so Its just an oversized deck in my thinking. Already there are 2 adequate concrete buttresses 3feet wide , and plenty deep. Span is 34 feet.. plus it will lap over 3 feet onto the buttresses and anchor in some fashion.

What's available budget wise is wood. Best i can find is custom made pressure treated solid beams, Douglas fir, 5-1/2" wide by 16 tall. I plan to stack 3 levels of 6x6 in various staggered lengths. 20 footers is the longest i can get  without going into a crazy high price range.

Plus access to area will not allow a crane or heavy equipment. So come-alongs, roll on pipes and steel bars and lifting is what I got. once i stack it 3 tall with 6x6's i will bolt and glue 6x6s to the left and right side .So a joined, glued and bolted 16-1/2w  by 15 1/2 tall beam.. will cover beams with 3 by 8,s and use 8 inch washer head screws..cars and trucks will need to drive over it. I'm guessing 4 of these with spacing 2 about a foot apart on either side at average tire width will be sufficient..

No legal access to put vertical supports under span..has to go end to end.. You think 4 will do it??? Atop the perpendicular 3x8's will be 2 tire runners of 2x8 p.t., layed out 32" wide so we can easily change when worn. Gonna oil it and use tar where beams rest on concrete to prevent rot. and tar top of beams and all cracks of natural joinery to prevent water seeping in.. Ideas? experiences??

Comment: An interesting project to be sure, but voting to close as too broad. No clear question was posed, and structural engineering is a fair bit off topic for a home improvement community. Chris, be aware that we're not a discussion forum. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if that's a surprise. Good luck with your build.

Comment: http://www.backwoodshome.com/build-a-graceful-footbridge/

Answer (score 1):

A lousy way to go at it. It's not a novel problem, and there are good established solutions for spanning a gap longer than your lumber efficiently and effectively.  A simple beam is a terribly inefficient bridge (you can spell inefficient as *expensive.*)

http://www.mdcoveredbridges.com/trusses.html

The Town lattice truss is by far the most common one I see in bridges that are still in service today - the one closest to me has a 16,000 lb posting.

http://www.nycoveredbridges.org/truss-styles/

[image: Town lattice truss]

The shed/barn around the bridge is a proven effective way to keep it dry, but you can try some other method if you like.